# Cannot boot. Diskutil list show two partitions with missing type and Name

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, startup

My Mac cannot boot BigSur but can boot up bootcamp. Start up with recovery mode and run diskutil list, missing Macintosh HD and Recovery partition but saw two partitions without name and type. Only show the UUID.

Please help. Thank you.

[image: diskutil and gpt info]

Update1: Mac was boot up via Internet Recovery. Diskutil apfs doesn’t recognized. Not sure if Apple upload a old version of utilities tool. Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Update 2: Managed to boot up Internet recovery with the latest version as suggested using cmd+opt+r. Now it recognized show Macintosh HD with APFS container. Tried to verify Macintosh HD but failed. Please help.

[image][image]

Updates 3: Managed to mount disk2s5 for Macintosh HD

[image]
[image]

Comment: Having 16 GB of free space at the end of the drive seems unusually. The Boot Camp Assistant normally places a Windows installation at the end of a drive. Otherwise the output looks normal. I assume you booted to an older version of OS X Recovery. A version that does not recognize APFS containers or Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE).

Comment: diskutil *should* recognise the verb apfs. The photo unfortunately doesn't show the command you typed, but I'd be suspicious of the recovery version if it doesn't know what apfs is - it could indicate the entire output is incorrect. Maybe try booting to Internet Recovery to be certain of the OS version.

Comment: @Tetsujin: What make you think the OP did not boot to Internet Recovery? I just assumed this.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I’m just puzzled that it doesn’t understand apfs

Comment: quicksilver: Apparently, you booted to an old version of OS X Recovery over the Internet. You could consider trying the key combination Option-Command-R. See [How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for the tips. Managed to get the newer recovery tools but now failed to verify the Macintosh HD. I have appended more detail on the tread. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Can you use the command line to mount `Macintosh HD - Data`? In other words, will the command `disktuil mount disk2s5` respond with the output `Volume Macintosh HD - Data on disk2s5 mounted`? Before entering the command, check to see if the identifiers have changed since posting your last image. Also, @Tetsujin might have a better idea what to do next.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - I do appreciate your vote of confidence, but you do always seem better at this 'low down' stuff than me. I was just throwing in a 'hmm, seems odd':)  Now we have recognition of the apfs container, I definitely bow to your expertise in that area.

Comment: @DavidAnderson disk2s5 is Macintosh HD. Not Macintosh HD - Data. I managed to mount disk2s5. Uploaded the screenshot to the thread...

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you for participating this quest. Appreciate your response as well

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I meant `disk2s1`. I really do not have any idea how to get macOS to boot other than to erase and reinstall. If you can mount the `Macintosh HD - Data` volume, then hopefully you can first save any important documents to another volume.

Comment: disk2s1 failed to mount :(